# MTG charmed sleep

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a question about the card [Charmed Sleep](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCharmed%20Sleep%5d).

The card reads

> Enchant creature
>   When Charmed Sleep enters the battlefield, tap enchanted creature.
>   Enchanted creature doesn't untap during its controller's untap step.

Does that mean that creature is basically useless unless I get rid of the enchantment? From my understanding if I can 'never' untap it (unless a spell allows me to) then I can't block or attack correct?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games SE!  We only allow one question per question on SE, so I removed your second question (in addition to generally cleaning things up.)  You're welcome to ask it, but it needs to be a separate post.

Answer (score 5):

### Your understanding is correct

While a creature is tapped, it cannot attack, block, used activated abilities that require tapping, or pay costs that require tapping.

There are many abilities creatures can have that do not require tapping (eg "Whenever a creature enters the battlefield, gain 1 life").  Those abilities will function normally.

As long as a creature is enchanted by Charmed Sleep, it will not untap naturally, but other effects can untap it and allow it to be used.

Comment: Re "*it cannot attack, block, used activated abilities that require tapping, or pay costs that require tapping*", Better wording: "it can't attack, it can't block, and it can't be tapped to pay a cost or for any other reason.

Comment: @ikemami I beg to differ: if you manage to untap via a different ability it can block and attack. If you get the creature to have vigilance, it can attack without tapping even. And this creature is still a valid sacrifice, if you need some... Vigilance especially is of concern, as it means "does not tap to attack"

Comment: @Trish That whole paragraph starts with "While a creature is tapped", so your "if you manage to untap" objection is moot. Also, nothing in this answer, nor in ikegami's comment contradict anything you say. So I don't know that you mean when you say "I beg to differ". However, I do see the merit of pointing out that the creature can be used in the ways you describe.

Comment: @arthur I say, that the wording as is in the answer is better and the proposed change is for the worse